# How to print a webgrid in Landscape in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net

Can any one help me in printing a webgrid in landscape

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in CSS, defining a stylesheet appropriate for printing. You can't control the printer preferences from a browser.

In other words, is up to the user to select the paper orientation he wants to use. You can only "help it"  a bit using appropriate styles for printing. [Read here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: @user1026644 No, I couldn't because I don't know how your page looks

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to this is to create a **custom print CSS stylesheet**. It can be pretty simple.

[This short article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/) will guide you through a simple example.

Once you grasp the concepts involved, you can add specific CSS for your web page.

Here are the basic steps:

1) Reset all the padding and margins:

```
body {margin:0; padding:0; line-height: 1.4em; word-spacing:1px; 
letter-spacing:0.2px; font: 13px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif;
 color: #000;}
```

2) Remove elements you don't want to print, such as the page header, logo, menus, etc. In your case, you may want to hide everything but the grid.

```
#logo, #catnavi, .topnavi, .more-link, .navigation, #sidebartop, #related, #social,
#sponsors, .tabs, #allpost, .toolbar, .splitbox, #commentform, #commentabs .idTabs, 
.postmeta-content .comments, #respond h3, .tag, .footerlinks {display:none;}
```

3) Optionally, display the URL in the print document (hiding links will hide the URL)

4) Optionally, insert page breaks

```
#comments {page-break-before: always;}
```

5) Add a `<link>` tag at the top of the page to include the `.css` file.

Comment: Thanks with the help of css i can able to pick up the contents what i need to print,but how to change the orientation of it to landscape in CSS.